# Why is this type incomplete when using the PIMPL idiom?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, incomplete-type, gotw

I'm using the PIMPL idiom, and specifically I'm using the template provided from [this post](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/).  Given the set of classes below and compiling with VS2015 Update 3, I'm getting compile errors:

> Error  C2027   use of undefined type 'C::C_impl' (compiling source file src\A.cpp)
>
> Error  C2338   can't delete an incomplete type (compiling source file src\A.cpp)
>
> Warning    C4150   deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'C::C_impl'; no destructor called (compiling source file src\A.cpp)

I can resolve this by uncommenting `C::~C()`, which leads me to believe that something is preventing `~C()` from being automatically generated but I don't understand what.  According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), the destructor for type T is implicitly defined as deleted if any of the following is true:

> 1. T has a non-static data member that cannot be destructed (has deleted or inaccessible destructor)
> 2. T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be destructed (has deleted or inaccessible destructors)
> 3. T is a union and has a variant member with non-trivial destructor.
> 4. The implicitly-declared destructor is virtual (because the base class has a virtual destructor) and the lookup for the deallocation function (operator delete() results in a call to ambiguous, deleted, or inaccessible function.

Items #2, 3, and 4 obviously do not apply to `C`, and I don't believe that #1 applies because `pimpl<>` (`C`'s only member) defines a destructor explicitly.

Can someone please explain what's going on?

A.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Pimpl.h>

class A
{
private:
    struct A_impl;
    pimpl<A_impl> m_pimpl;
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "C.h"

class B
{
private:
    C m_C;
};
```

C.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Pimpl.h>

class C
{
public:
    // Needed for the PIMPL pattern
    //~C();

private:
    struct C_impl;
    pimpl<C_impl> m_pimpl;
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include <PimplImpl.h>

struct A::A_impl
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_pB;
};

// Ensure all the code for the template is compiled
template class pimpl<A::A_impl>;
```

C.cpp

```
#include <C.h>
#include <PimplImpl.h>

struct C::C_impl { };

// Needed for the PIMPL pattern
//C::~C() = default;

// Ensure all the code for the template is compiled
template class pimpl<C::C_impl>;
```

For completeness, the PIMPL implementation from the post referenced above:

pimpl.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class pimpl
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> m;
public:
    pimpl();
    template<typename ...Args> pimpl(Args&& ...);
    ~pimpl();
    T* operator->();
    T& operator*();
};
```

PimplImpl.h

```
#pragma once
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::pimpl() : m{ new T{} } {}

template<typename T>
template<typename ...Args>
pimpl<T>::pimpl(Args&& ...args)
    : m{ new T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } }
{
}

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::~pimpl() {}

template<typename T>
T* pimpl<T>::operator->() { return m.get(); }

template<typename T>
T& pimpl<T>::operator*() { return *m.get(); }
```

A few notes about the code above:

- I'm trying to expose `A` and `C` to consumers of my library and keep `B` internal.
- There is no B.cpp here, it would be empy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the C destructor manually after definition C::C_impl because for default compiler tries to generate C destructor in point of usage, but it can be point where C::C_impl definition can not be found (for example, it can be B.cpp).

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't realize it was generated at point of usage.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `std::unique_ptr` requires knowing the destruction function (ie, the destructor) at time of instantiation.

With the default destructor `~C()` the compiler generates it at point of usage, which means that it is trying to delete the `pimpl<C_impl>` object with the information available to it in `A.cpp`.  Of course, since `C_impl` is only declared at that point the compiler does not know how to destroy a `C_impl` object and that is the error you receive.

Uncommenting `~C();` tells the compiler not to worry about how to destroy a `C_impl`, that will be defined somewhere else.  In your case that is defined in `C.cpp` where the definition of `C_impl` is known.

In response to your edit, the destructor for `pimpl<C_impl>` has `std::unique_ptr<C_impl>` which has a non-static data member with inaccessible destructor (`C_impl` is an incomplete type at point of usage withing `A.cpp`).